# OpenESB - EmailBC: Attached File

Tags: email, bpel

I'm working on a BPEL in OpenESB for sending emails with attachment files.

I have installed the email binding component and I followed the steps described in the manual, so now my BPEL is able to send an email with an attachment file.

I have added the option SMTPAttachemnt in the binding as you can see in the image :

[image: screenshot]

But I have a problem because the bpel receives a base64 encode file, so when I check my email inbox the file attached remains encode :(

So I think if I want to receive the file decoded in my email inbox,  I would have to decode the "attachedFile" element before sending the email. My question is: what's the best way to decode the a base64 encode file element in OpenESB ?

Thanks in advance!!

I will look forward to hearing your solutions,
Girish

Answer (score 0):

You can use direct java call from BPEL itself. on java-6, we use it like

DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary("encoded="); just map input and outputs.